# SELECT QUERY within ORACLE INSERT QUERY

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using ORACLE 10g as database.

Consider two tables:
1.)  ABC with column A as primary key and rest can hold null values
2.)  XYZ with column W as primary key and rest can hold null values

Also the datatypes for peers are same
Example:  A = W , B=X , C=Y , D=Z
 Equality means the datatypes are same

The following query runs perfectly fine

```
INSERT INTO ABC(A ,B,C,D) 
VALUES ('klm'  , (SELECT X FROM XYX WHERE W ='SOME_VALUE') , 'Dsl' , 'rwz')
```

But the following query doesn't work.. If someone could help me out ?

```
INSERT INTO ABC(A,B,C,D) 
VALUES ( (SELECT W, X , Y , Z FROM XYX WHERE W ='SOME_VALUE') )
```

NOTE: The value of W is not in table ABC. No Constraint violation

> Error report: SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values
>   00947. 00000 -  "not enough values"

Please explain??

Insert into ABC(A,B,C,D) VALUES('123' , (SELECT X,Y,Z from XYZ where W = 'same_value')) I need a solution to this generic thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `values` constructor and use the `Select` query directly after the `Insert`.

Try this way

```
INSERT INTO ABC(A,B,C,D) 
SELECT W, X , Y , Z FROM XYX WHERE W ='SOME_VALUE'
```

**Update**

Just hard code the value(123) in `Select` list

```
INSERT INTO ABC(A,B,C,D) 
SELECT 123, X , Y , Z FROM XYX WHERE W ='SOME_VALUE'
```

Comment: Hey,Thanks for the quick response Each time I don't  do the same way, 
Insert into ABC(A,B,C,D) VALUES('123' , (SELECT X,Y,Z from XYZ where W = 'same_value'))
 I need a solution to this generic thing